# Limit About Complex Variable

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to see if I have right understanding of the limit.

when the book mentions

$$\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z) = L$$

this just means that $f(z_0) = L$ is this correct?

Comment: Why would they write a few words there if it were just to mean $f(z_0)=L$?

Answer (score 1):

No. $f(z_0)$ need not be even be defined.

Answer (score 0):

No. It means the the value of $f(z)$ **is arbitrarily close** to $L$ as $z\to z_0$. Consider a case when $f(z_0)$ is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'll consider the limit towards points $z_0$ where the functions is defined and it therefore doesn't make sense to write $f(z_0)$. If $f$ is defined and continuous at $z_0$, the limit is equal to the value (that is more or less the meaning of continuity).